# Is the street fight in "They Live" the longest clocked street fight in a film?

Tags: stunts

Now discounting satires or films that are specifically about fighting...

Is the brawl between Nada and Frank in "They Live" the longest non-stop fight in a film?
It's clocked at around 5 minutes of (well, really silly) brawling.

(The fight in its entirety can be [found on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-MVMbm6c0k))

[image: Image from "They Live"]

Comment: didnt' they recreate this fight in South Park?

Comment: Yes, but that'd fall under satires.

Comment: At least I heard or read it somewhere to be, but I guess you heard or read that, too, which is why you're asking this question.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure how I feel about this. Longest fight in terms of one shot? The fight itself? If it's tagged martial arts, longest martial arts fight or just longest street fight?

Comment: I always assumed the fight was meant for the pro-wrestling fans in the audience, as the movie's star Rowdy Roddy Piper came from the pro-wrestling world

Comment: Could the OP please clarify this is still a rather vague question.

Comment: Cut or not cut? Otherwise the Vader SkyWalker fight in RotJ is 12 minutes...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Added examples, all over 5:05 - hopefully will lose the downvote.

I would say no, principally because of Jackie Chan. His movies like Supercop and Rumble in the Bronx are basically 90-minute street fights punctuated with bursts of dialogue.

A few excerpts from the master of the running non-stop fight:

- [Who Am I](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjkSC4SQORw) as an example clocks in at over 5:05.
- [Wheels on Meals](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&v=UrlxwlCHFXY&NR=1) - 9 min+

Also the final act of Kill Bill Pt. 1 is pretty much a non-stop fight:

- [Bride vs. B-squad Crazy 88s and O-Ren Ishii](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVDl16kvkYM) with The Bride versus the Crazy 88s clocks in at over 6:30 (1:15 to 7:45)- warning: includes blood, gore and a gratitutious sword-spanking. She does pause a few seconds between some kills.

Both together would clock in at almost 20 mins but there is a breather after she finishes off Gogo.

Comment: I didn't DV, but I would guess it was because the OP specifically asked "longest *non-stop* fight"

Comment: Not sure if all these fights are very continuous fights like the question intended.

Comment: I would doubt if all those are shot in their entirety without any cuts.

Comment: What do you mean by cuts? There are shot changes about every 5-10 seconds in the They Live clip. Professional actors and filmmakers excel at making those scenes look continuous, but that scene is full of cuts for visual pacing. Same with Who Am I and Wheels on Meals.

Comment: @Ionstar - see Oldboy for an awesome (and long) uncut fight scene.

Answer (score 4):

It's a great scene in a great film but the fights in [Eastwood](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000142/)'s "[Every Which Way But Loose](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077523/)" and "[Any Which Way You Can](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080377/)" were clearly longer, as was [John Wayne](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000078/)'s excellent "[The Quiet Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045061/)".

Answer (score 3):

Thirteen Assassins has got to top the list. The final battle is over 45 minutes of nonstop fighting. No dialogue breaks, no plot twists, just thirteen badasses against two hundred hired goons.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have measurements to hand but wasn't the sword fight which ended up in the wheels in the pirates of the Caribbean sequel longer than 5 minutes?

Also, do battle scenes count? The dday sequence of saving private Ryan is longer than 5 minutes.

Comment: I would doubt if all those were shot in their entirety without any cuts.

Comment: Ah, so it has to be done in 1 cut?  I thought it just had to be a fight scene without a cut away to another scene.